# Error al realizar consulta PHP en Android

Tags: php, mysql, android, login, conexión

Saludos mi problema es el siguiente: Estoy comenzando con Android e inicie un proyecto para una App, el problema es que antes funcionaba la conexión de BD y realizaba mis consultas sin problema pero **sin haber hecho nada una semana** y al volver a retomar el trabajo cuando realizo consultas me devuelve error de conexión.
Extrañado voy al hosting y esta arriba, reviso conexion remota y tambien tengo acceso a la BD. Cuando reviso el log de errores de MySQL encuentro esto:

```
[03-Dec-2021 09:45:14 America/Caracas] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'belmenyc_AppVentas.B040_Usuarios' doesn't exist in /home/belmenyc/public_html/android/Login.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 /home/belmenyc/public_html/android/Login.php(13): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/belmenyc/public_html/android/Login.php on line 13
```

A continuacion les muestro como establezco la conexion:

**Config.php**

```
<?php

// $DBhost = 'localhost';
$DBhost = 'EL HOST';
$DBuser = 'EL USUARIO';
$DBpass = 'LA CLAVE';
$DBname = 'belmenyc_AppVentas';
 
 try{
  
  $DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$DBhost;dbname=$DBname",$DBuser,$DBpass);
  $DBcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
 }catch(PDOException $ex){
  
  die($ex->getMessage());
 }
 
?>
```

**Login.php:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
    require_once 'config.php';
 
    $usuario=$_GET['usuario'];
    $clave=$_GET['clave'];
    
    $consulta = "SELECT Usuario, Nombre FROM B040_Usuarios WHERE usuario = '". $usuario  ."' AND clave = '". $clave ."' AND activo = 1"; 
     
 $stmt = $DBcon->prepare($consulta);
 $stmt->execute();
 
 $userData = array();
 
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  
  $userData['Usuario'][] = $row;
 }
 
 echo json_encode($userData);
 
 ?>
```

**Estructura de la base de datos:**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for b040_usuarios
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `b040_usuarios`;
CREATE TABLE `b040_usuarios` (
  `Usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CodVendedor` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CodSupervisor` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CodGerente` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Activo` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Usuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda al respecto porque la verdad no se que ocurre y la verdad veo que la App no es el problema. Saludos

Comment: La tabla se llama B040_Usuarios. Ya verifique y sigue alli en la base de datos

Comment: Alli tienes la informacion. a base de datos no tenia problemas hasta ahora y probando con un programa hecho en .NET le llego sin problemas

Comment: Pues ahi esta tu problema... estás buscando la tabla `B040_Usuarios` cuando la tabla se llama `b040_usuarios`, puedes probar corrigiendo ese detalle primero. Si la BD es case sensitive, la diferencia de mayúsculas será un problema.

Comment: Amigo tienes razon: era eso TODO  debia ir en minusculas. Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Procederé a agregar como respuesta para que la marques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el error se menciona claramente:

> Table 'belmenyc_AppVentas.B040_Usuarios' doesn't exist

Tabla `B040_Usuarios` NO EXISTE.
Por lo que es apto revisar el nombre de la tabla.

Al pedirle la tabla al OP, notamos que hay diferencias de mayúsculas:
`b040_usuarios`
Si existen diferencias de mayúsculas, pueden existir problemas de `case sensitive`, en donde solo por mayúsculas y minúsculas, tengamos problemas como este.

Por lo que solo basta con corregir el error en la consulta

```
$consulta = "SELECT Usuario, Nombre 
FROM b040_usuarios 
WHERE usuario = '". $usuario  ."' AND clave = '". $clave ."' AND activo = 1";
```